# Clear Column Contents in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to clear the column contents in google script instead of deleting the column? i have tried setting the values a few times but i couldnot delete the contents of the column as the range is dynamic

```
function onEdit(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if( activeSheet.getName() == "UAT" ) {
    var activeRange = ss.getActiveRange();
    var activeRow = activeRange.getRow();
    var activeColumn = activeRange.getColumn()
    if( activeColumn >= 3 && activeRow == 70 ) { 
      if ( activeRange.getValue() == "Completed" )
        var coltemp = activeColumn;
        var rowtemp = activeRow;


  var sourcespreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // set the "Placeholder sheet as active  
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sourcespreadsheet.getSheets()[1]);
  var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var targetspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // set Master sheet as target
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(targetspreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  var targetsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();


  var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange((targetsheet.getLastRow()+1), 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
  var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  targetrange.setValues(rangeValues);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.hideSheet();

  // set the UAT sheet as active  
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sourcespreadsheet.getSheets()[2]);
  var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  /* var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if( activeSheet.getName() == "UAT" ) { 
    var activeRange = ss.getActiveRange();
    var activeRow = activeRange.getRow();
    var activeColumn = activeRange.getColumn()
    if( activeColumn >= 3 && activeRow == 70 ) { // Column EC
      if ( activeRange.getValue() == "Completed" ) */


        activeSheet.deleteColumn( coltemp );

       // i would prefer to delete the values of the column (coltemp )instead of deleting the column

      /*   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('clear column values');
      var rowd = 1;
      for(rowd = 1; rowd <= 200; rowd++)
      {ss.getRange(coltemp+rowd).setValue(rowd);}

      */



    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('thank you for participating in eco survey');
}}}
```

How would be you able to target a dynamic column and clear the contents
i would prefer to delete the values of the column (coltemp )instead of deleting the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete the contents of the column of `coltemp` which can be seen your script. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- Delete the contents using `clearContent()`.

#### Modified script :

Please modify as follows.

From :

```
activeSheet.deleteColumn( coltemp );
```

To :

```
activeSheet.getRange(1, coltemp, activeSheet.getLastRow(), 1).clearContent();
```

#### Note :

- This modified script deletes the contents of all cells in a column.

#### Reference :

- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thanks Alot tanaike, that's wat i was looking for

Comment: @lazyezy Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.